# Powershell Script output to variable - capture Write-Host output

Tags: powershell, io-redirection

Using this script: https://github.com/byterogues/powershell-bittrex-api
which I call from another script.

e.g.

```
$order = .\bittrex-api.ps1 -action buylimit -market BTC-TX -quantity 1 -rate 0.00011300
```

bittrex-api.ps1 catches an error and shows this on screen

*BITTREX ERROR: API Query returned an error.
Error Message: MIN_TRADE_REQUIREMENT_NOT_MET*

How can I capture the output from bittrex-api.ps1 into a variable so I can use this variable in my base script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The script uses `Write-Host` to output the error. `Write-Host` only writes text to the console, it doesn't return any objects which means there's nothing to capture.

I would recommend modifying the script to use other cmdlets like `Write-Error`, `Write-Output` or any other `Write-*` which outputs to a stream (which you can redirect to the stdout-stream and save).

See http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 6):

To complement [Frode F.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49087217/45375), which sensibly recommends modifying the script to use `Write-Error` for error reporting:

If modifying the code is not an option and you're using **PSv5+**, **you *can* capture `Write-Host` output**, because since PSv5 `Write-Host` writes to the newly introduced information output stream (to which primarily `Write-Information` is designed to write):

PowerShell's output streams are numbered, and the information stream has number `6` so that output-redirection expression **`6>&1` redirects the information stream into the success output stream**, whose number is `1`, allowing regular capturing in a variable, as the following example shows:

```
# PSv5+

$captured = Write-Host 'write-host output' 6>&1

$captured # output what was captured -> 'write-host output'
```

To learn more about PowerShell's output streams and redirection, run [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)

Note:

- `Write-Host` output captured via `6>&1` consists of one or more [`System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord) instances, which *print* as if they were strings, namely by their `.MessageData.Message` property value, which is the string content of the argument(s) passed to `Write-Host`.
- Therefore, any *coloring* that stems from the use of the `-ForegroundColor` and `-BackgroundColor` parameters is *not* (directly) passed through:

  - However, the information *is* preserved, namely in the `.MessageData.ForegroundColor` and `.MessageData.BackgroundColor` properties, along with the information about whether `-NoNewLine` was passed to `Write-Host`, in Boolean property `.MessageData.NoNewLine`
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74748696/45375) shows how to *recreate* the original coloring from the captured objects.
- By contrast, coloring via ANSI / VT escape sequences *embedded in the original string argument(s)* is preserved.

---

Note: To capture the output *and also pass it through* (to the *success* output stream), you have two options:

- Simply enclose the statement in [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--), but note that output will only show *after all output has been collected*.

  ```
  ($captured = Write-Host 'write-host output' 6>&1)
  ```
- For *streaming* pass-through, use [`Tee-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object) with the `-Variable` parameter:

  ```
  Write-Host 'write-host output' 6>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable captured
  ```

The above techniques generally work for capturing and passing success-stream output through, irrespective of whether redirections are involved.

Comment: How would you get both the output displayed **and** results put into the variable?

Comment: @not2qubit, please see my update; the required techniques aren't specific to dealing with `Write-Host` output.

Comment: Hi I tried that, but coloring is lost in the output. `Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "[ERROR]: Package id: ""jaja""  not found!" 6>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable zz`. Posted a separate question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74748384/how-to-get-both-the-output-and-results-to-a-varibale-using-write-host-in-powersh).