# Command output in function vs method

Tags: powershell

I'd like to see the "live" output of an application when I call it.

When I call it in a **function**, it works properly, as if I would call it directly.
I can cancel the application with Ctrl+C and the "progress bar" the application outputs is updated:

```
function Test()
{
    dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore
}

Test
```

```
[===                        5.5%                           ]
```

When I call it in a **method** however, there is no output visible.
I can work around that by writing `& dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore 2>&1 | Write-Host` but for this example, it would not update the progress bar but instead write a new line whenever there's a progress update:

```
class TestC
{
    Test()
    {
        & dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore 2>&1 | Write-Host
    }
}

$testC = [TestC]::new()
$testC.Test()
```

```
[=                          3.3%                           ]

[===                        5.5%                           ]
```

I also cannot cancel the application with Ctrl+C, instead only the script would be cancelled and the called application continues in the background.

Is there an explanation for this? And a working workaround? :)

Thank you!

Comment: Good question, but I'd be surprised if Ctrl-C didn't also terminate the external program when called from a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Start-Process` cmdlet with the `-NoNewWindow` parameter:

```
Start-Process dism.exe -ArgumentList "/online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

Comment: What's a bit unfortunate is that when I cancel the process with Ctrl+C, it continues with the output after the script has already ended:

`PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\APPS\Scripts\Tools.ps1

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17763.771

Image Version: 10.0.17763.1131

[=========                  16.4%                          ]
PS C:\Users\Administrator>

Error: 1223

Operation was incomplete because of a cancel request.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log`

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Thomas' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61711172/45375) with some background information:

You cannot use *direct invocation* in PowerShell classes if you want to invoke external console applications with *pass-through display output*.

Methods produce (success) output only via the `return` statement (and to report errors via `throw`).

Note that - both with your `Write-Host` attempt and with `Start-Process -NoNewWindow` (which is the only way to pass output through to the display, albeit *invariably*) - you won't be able to capture or redirect the external program's output.<sup>[1]</sup>

If you do want to *return* an external program's output *as data* from a class method, you'll have to define it as follows:

```
class TestC
{
  [string[]] Test()
  {
    return dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore 2>&1
  }
}
```

Note the `[string[]]` return type and the use of `return`.

This outputs the external program's output lines in a streaming fashion to the caller, allowing further programmatic processing.

Of course, outputting *progress* messages this way won't be useful.

---

<sup>[1] Technically, you *can* capture `Write-Host` output since PowerShell 5, namely via the *information* stream (`6`), which in your case would require `$output = & { $testC.Test() } 6>&1` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49102708/45375).</sup>