# How to get both the output and results to a variable using Write-Host in powershell?

Tags: powershell, output

I just came across a funny behavior when using `Write-Host` on powershell.

What I wanted to do is get the colored output from `Write-Host` and concurrently save the result in a variable. Checking other SO questions, led me to try the following:

```
$zz = &{
   Write-Warning "hello"
   Write-Error "hello"
   Write-Output "hi"
} 3>&1 2>&1

$zz 
#WARNING: hello
#Write-Error: hello
#hi

$zz = &{ Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "[ERROR]: Package id: ""jaja""  not found!"; } 3>&1 2>&1
# [ERROR]: Package id: "jaja"  not found!

$zz
# [nothing]
```

[image]

The output was surprising, and I could not find a way to have the output saved into a variable while also see it displayed, unlike when using the other `Write-xxx` commandlets.

**Q: What's gong on and how can I get both the output shown and save the results into a variable?**

---

`REFERENCES:`

- [Powershell Stream Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Powershell Script output to variable - capture Write-Host output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087085/powershell-script-output-to-variable-capture-write-host-output)
- [PowerShell Capture Write-Host output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937190/powershell-capture-write-host-output)
- [PowerShell redirect output to Write-Host and return exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71257605/powershell-redirect-output-to-write-host-and-return-exit-code)

---

**UPDATE-1**

Thanks to *mklement0*'s updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49102708/1147688), I also tried the following, which almost does what I want, but **does not produce the color**.

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "[ERROR]: Package id: ""jaja""  not found!" 6>&1 | Tee-Object -Variable zz

($zz = Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "[ERROR]: Package id: ""$package""  not found!" 6>&1)
```

[image]

The conclusion seem to be that any coloring information is lost when using anything that has to do with redirecting output from `Write-Host`.

---

**UPDATE-2**

Interestingly, the color information are still *"there"* somewhere. Following mklement0's suggestion, I tried to save the color info for 2 different lines. But then the parsing is not correct, as shown below.

So with:

```
$captured = &{ Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewline "[ERROR]: some error! " 6>&1; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "OKAY"  6>&1 }
```

We get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [the answer you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49102708/45375), you need **redirection `6>&1`** in order to **capture `Write-Host` output** (only works in PowerShell v5 and above):

- `Write-Host` output captured via `6>&1` consists of one or more [`System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.InformationRecord) instances, which *print* as if they were strings, namely by their `.MessageData.Message` property value, which is the string content of the argument(s) passed to [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host).
- Therefore, any *coloring* that stems from the use of the `-ForegroundColor` and `-BackgroundColor` parameters is *not* (directly) passed through:

  - However, the information *is* preserved, namely in the `.MessageData.ForegroundColor` and `.MessageData.BackgroundColor` properties, along with the information about whether `-NoNewLine` was passed to `Write-Host`, in Boolean property `.MessageData.NoNewLine`
- By contrast, coloring via ANSI / VT escape sequences *embedded in the original string argument(s)* is preserved.

Thus, you can ***recreate* the original coloring** as follows - note that `Write-Host` is again used:

```bash
$captured = Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "[ERROR]: some error" 6>&1

$captured | ForEach-Object {
  $messageData = $_.MessageData
  $colorArgs = @{}
  if (-1 -ne $messageData.ForegroundColor) { $colorArgs.ForegroundColor = $messageData.ForegroundColor }
  if (-1 -ne $messageData.BackgroundColor) { $colorArgs.BackgroundColor = $messageData.BackgroundColor }
  Write-Host -Object $captured @colorArgs -NoNewline:$messageData.NoNewLine
}
```

Comment: Wow, cool. (I seriously would never have tried to learn powershell if it was not for all your awesome SO contributions. Thank you! ✨) I tried the above with 2 different `Write-Host` objects, but then the parsing is not quite right, as I showed in OP update. It would have been cool to be able to have a *function* or *filter* which could spit out the original objects, regardless how many. OTH, I am now thinking that perhaps it's just easier to write your own ANSI coloring functions and pray they don't generate garbage on the users terminal...

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, and I appreciate the nice feedback, @not2qubit. As for your update: the output _is_ correct, as it also tries to recreate the effects of the `-NoNewLine` switch. Remove `-NoNewline:$messageData.NoNewLine` if you don't want that. Defining a `function` or `filter` based on the above is trivial, but for such a function / filter to handle _other_ types meaningfully too, more work would be needed.